# ECK Elasticsearch node state “Invalid” after install node using yaml file

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

if follow the guide from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/1.0/k8s-quickstart.html#k8s-deploy-elasticsearch, but after install node using following yaml code,

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1  
kind: Elasticsearch 
metadata:   
name: quickstart 
spec:   
version: 8.0.0   
nodeSets:
  - name: default          
    count: 1     
    config:    
      node.master: true   
      node.data: true    
      node.ingest: true  
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

and then i get error "invalid", after issuing following command:

$kubectl get elasticsearch
NAME         VERSION   PHASE     AGE
quickstart                     8.0.0     Invalid   6h3m

Comment: What does it say if you `describe` the resource?

Comment: Hi @jordanm thanks for the response, base on documentaation above, i have installed elastic operator and elastic node. Elastic operator is running well and the pod is created. But for elastic node as i have seen the pod hasn't been created. So how should i describe the resource ? Which resource it mean ? Thanks

Comment: `kubectl describe elasticsearch quickstart`